# Multiple time series lines in Plotly.js

Tags: time-series, plotly

I am hoping to use plot.ly to graph multiple time series lines.

I am using the following code:

```
var trace1 = [
  {
    x: ['2013-10-04 22:23:00', '2013-11-04 22:23:00', '2013-12-04 22:23:00'],
    y: [1, 3, 6],mode: 'lines',
    type: 'scatter'
  }
];

var trace2 = [
  {
    x: ['2013-10-04 22:23:00', '2013-11-04 22:23:00', '2013-12-04 22:23:00'],
    y: [1, 2, 4],mode: 'lines',
    type: 'scatter'
  }
];

var data = [trace1, trace2];


Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

But nothing appears. Does anyone know if it is possible to make them with Plotly.js?

Comment: You have extra square brackets around the traces so that will not work. If you remove these then you will be able to plot the data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

plotly traces need to be objects not arrays. This should work:

```
var trace1 = {
    x: ['2013-10-04 22:23:00', '2013-11-04 22:23:00', '2013-12-04 22:23:00'],
    y: [1, 3, 6],mode: 'lines',
    type: 'scatter'
  };

var trace2 = {
    x: ['2013-10-04 22:23:00', '2013-11-04 22:23:00', '2013-12-04 22:23:00'],
    y: [1, 2, 4],mode: 'lines',
    type: 'scatter'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];


Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```